# Illustrator: Exporting in 0,5 with 'export for screens' doesn't export in truly halve the size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

I have a problem that drives me crazy, I have a lot of artboards that are exactly 32x32. The content on it is pixel perfect. I want to export all those artboards in 16x16 in the .png format using 'export for screens'. The result I get is that they all change dimensions after exporting.

Starting point:

[image]

After exporting:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no answer to you question, but would recommend using slices instead of artboards. Slices have several benefits over artboards. Another option might be to scale the exported 32px icons to 16 in Photoshop. Should be the same result.

Comment: Align the x position to an even value instead of 343.

Comment: @LeoNas can't believe that worked.. Thanks a bunch! Still doesn't work for one icon on the artboard but I can live with that :)

Comment: I will post it as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Align the x position to an even value instead of 343.

this will prevent the pixel to shift to an even value.